# puppetmaster service start error in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, puppet

I have the following versions of ruby,rails and gem... I want to install pupetmaster in ubuntu 12.04. But when I try to install puppetmaster, I am getting the below error.

What could be the possible reasons? and how to fix it ?

```
ruby : ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]

rails: Rails 4.0.0

gem -v
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/home/lhdadmin/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- executable-hooks/wrapper (LoadError)
2.6.6

sudo gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.0.0)
actionpack (4.2.2, 4.0.0)
actionview (4.2.2)
activejob (4.2.2)
activemodel (4.2.2, 4.0.0)
activerecord (4.2.2, 4.0.0)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.4)
activesupport (4.2.2, 4.0.0)
arel (6.0.3, 4.0.2)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.2.2, 3.1.4)
bundler (1.12.5)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
globalid (0.3.7)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.8.3, 1.5.4)
loofah (2.0.3)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.25.1)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
minitest (5.9.0, 4.7.5, 2.5.1)
multi_json (1.12.1)
nokogiri (1.6.8)
pkg-config (1.1.7)
polyglot (0.3.5)
rack (1.6.4, 1.5.5)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.0.0)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
railties (4.0.0)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.4)
rubygems-update (2.6.6)
sprockets (2.12.4)
sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (1.2.2, 0.3.51)
```

And this is the error when I try to start the service

```
sudo service puppetmaster start
```

`* Starting puppet master`

> /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:1:in `require': no such file
>   to load -- optparse (LoadError)   from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:1     from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/puppet/application/master.rb:1:in`require'     from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/puppet/application/master.rb:1  from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:54:in `require'     from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:54:in`
>   require_application'     from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:59:in `execute'     from
>   /usr/bin/puppet:4

Comment: What version of puppet/puppetserver?

Comment: puppet version 2.7.x, I think master is 3.x

Comment: Ok so your version of ruby is supported. Next thing to check is why you think your version of ruby is 1.9.3 and Puppet thinks it is 1.8.7. Did you install Puppet with `gem` or `apt`? As always, consider upgrading to the minimum supported version of Puppet (3.8.7).

Comment: this is how I am trying to install sudo apt-get install puppetmaster. Do I have to give specific version ? Why its taking 1.8.7 ? any idea?

Comment: Since you installed with `apt`, it will be using your system ruby. You have to use `gem` to use your alternative ruby install. Checking the documentation, I do not believe this is possible for the puppetmaster. Optparse comes with your base ruby install, so something is either messed up with that (somewhat unlikely), your gem loading path (likely), or the include path in the code (unlikely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These issues arise if you have a broken ruby installation.
In Ubuntu 12.04, to install puppetmaster service, you definitely need Ruby 1.9.3 as the system ruby.

If you are using rvm or chruby, make sure you are using the right version ( 1.9.3 ) and also make sure that you don't have a different version of ruby installed with rvm and different version of Ruby in system and there is conflicts of path in bashrc.